# DataContractJsonSerializer parsing iso 8601 date

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-8, .net-4.5

I have a json which has date as `2012-06-07T00:29:47.000` and has to be deserialized.
But on

```
 DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type);
 return (object)serializer.ReadObject(Util.GetMemoryStreamFromString(json));
```

I get below exception

```
There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1
[[MyNameSpace.MyClass, MyNameSpace, Version=1.0.4541.23433, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
 DateTime content '2012-06-07T00:29:47.000' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON
```

It is working in windows mobile 7
but the same code is not working in windows 8.

 It is expecting date format as `\/Date(1337020200000+0530)\/` instead of `2012-06-07T00:29:47.000`.

Does it require custom serialization if yes then how?
And I can't use `JSON.NET` I'm bound to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` and I can't change the format of the JSON as the same JSON is used for android.

**I'm new in .net.
Thanks.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use one string property for serialisation/deserialisation, and a separate, non-serialised property that converts it to a DateTime. Easier to see some sample code:

```
[DataContract]
public class LibraryBook
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ReturnDate")]
    // This can be private because it's only ever accessed by the serialiser.
    private string FormattedReturnDate { get; set; }

    // This attribute prevents the ReturnDate property from being serialised.
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    // This property is used by your code.
    public DateTime ReturnDate
    {
        // Replace "o" with whichever DateTime format specifier you need.
        // "o" gives you a round-trippable format which is ISO-8601-compatible.
        get { return DateTime.ParseExact(FormattedReturnDate, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
        set { FormattedReturnDate = value.ToString("o"); }
    }
}
```

You could do the parsing in the setter of FormattedReturnDate instead, to allow it to fail earlier if a bad date is received.

---

Edited to include [GôTô](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456167)'s suggestion to give the serialised DataMember the right name.

Comment: What is the date formatter for `2012-06-07T00:29:47.000` I have created this `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss` but don't know what to do with `.000`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore You can use `f`, e.g. `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff`. But the [standard format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) of `o` is [pretty close to that already](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip), though it will include a time zone if your DateTime.Kind is `Utc` or `Local`.

Comment: Very nice solution. You can even go a bit further by replacing `[DataMember]` with `[DataMember(Name="ReturnDate")]` to have the same name before and after serialization

Answer (score 1):

Pass the format in DataContractJsonSerializer constructor

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(
   typeof(Client),
   new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings {
       DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),
    });
```